# Android: Implement floating video player (like YouTube android app) with JW Player SDK

Tags: android, draggable, jwplayer, android-video-player, viewdraghelper

I am trying to implement Floating video player (like YouTube player which minimize when dragged to bottom right of the screen). For that I am using DraggablePanel library (https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel).

I was having some problem while integrating it with our production code so I try to integrate it with JW player sample app
(the VideoPlayer that we are using in our app is JW player). JW player sample app is on GitHub: https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer-sdk-android-demo

I changed only the xml layout. But its not working as expected.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/output2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/ccl_blue" />

    <com.github.pedrovgs.DraggableView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:draggable_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/draggable_view_my"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        draggable_view:bottom_view_id="@+id/output"
        draggable_view:top_view_id="@+id/linearlayout" //if i  give id of JWPlayerView, then app crashes. So i wrapped it inside a LinearLayout

        draggable_view:top_view_margin_right="1dp"
        draggable_view:top_view_resize="true"

        draggable_view:top_view_x_scale_factor="2.5"
        draggable_view:top_view_y_scale_factor="1.5"

        draggable_view:enable_click_to_maximize_view="false"     
        draggable_view:enable_click_to_minimize_view="false">  //this is not working. Player is getting minimised if i click on it


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.JWPlayerView
                android:id="@+id/jwplayer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp" />

        <TextView                            //this TextView is not coming. Neither in Expanded view nor in minimized view
            android:id="@+id/output"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#f01232"
            android:text="Bottom Text View" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.github.pedrovgs.DraggableView>

</FrameLayout>
```

1) The player is getting minimized even when `draggable_view:enable_click_to_minimize_view="false"`. So I am not able to pause the player or click any of the icons which appear
on the player skin. Sometimes I manage to click on the play/pause button in the expanded view mode but it also results in minimizing the player view as well.

2) video frames are not coming most of time when player is minimized. see below photo link. a white screen is coming at the bottom right corner.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnUPd.jpg

3) if I dismissed the minimized player view(by dragging it to left/right), the audio is still coming even though the VideoView is gone.

4) if i click on fullscreen icon on playerview then it goes fullscreen but instead of showing video frames only a white screen is coming.

5) Its really hard to maximize the player. You have to SLOWLY drag upwards the minimized view exactly from the center, otherwise the minimized view goes left or right and gets dismissed.

Is the library incompatible with JW PlayerView? or Is there any other library for the same? If there is no library then how can I achieve this in android?

Answer (score 1):

Floating video player like youtube is technically known as picture in picture mode. When you will back press the player minimize to right bottom corner. Even you can drag player to other position. It is little bit lengthy process but you can make it.
 [Here is reference tutorial.](https://www.blueappsoftware.com/floating-video-player-like-youtube-player/)